# SegFault on return statement C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, return, stack-corruption

The issue i am having with this code is when i am attempting to return the struct node * head within the addTrash function on the first iteration. I suspect it might be stack corruption but I do not know for sure and I don't know exactly how i would figure out what the error is within the code i have given you.

This is a doubly linked linked list that has value as the only data it holds.

```
struct node * modifyMainList( struct node *head, int link2Delete){

    struct node * curr = head;
    struct node * temp;
    int i = 0;  

    //traverse list link2Delete amount of times
    while(i != link2Delete){

        curr = curr -> next;
    }


    //head case
    if(curr -> previous == NULL){

        curr = curr -> next;            

        head = curr;
        return head;
    }

    //tail case 
    if(curr -> next == NULL){

        temp = curr;    
        curr = curr -> previous;

        curr -> next = NULL;
        temp -> previous = NULL;
        temp -> next = NULL;

        free(temp);
        return head;
    }

    curr -> previous -> next = curr -> next;
    curr -> next -> previous = curr -> previous;            


    curr -> previous = NULL;
    curr -> next = NULL;
    free(curr);
    return head;
}



struct node * addTrash(struct node *mainHead, int link2Delete){

    struct node * head = NULL;
    struct node * curr = mainHead;
    struct node * trashCurr = NULL;;
    struct node * temp = NULL;
    int i = 0;  

    printf("im in trash before loop\n\n");
    for(i = 0; i < link2Delete; i++){

        curr = curr -> next;
    }

    printf("im in trash before head size check\n\n");
    if(head == NULL){

        printf("im in trash with head == null\n\n");
        //head of main list
        if(link2Delete == 0){

            printf("im in trash link2delete == null\n\n");
            curr = curr -> previous;
            head = curr;

            curr = curr -> next;
            curr -> previous = NULL;
            curr -> next = NULL;
            return head;
        }

        printf("im in trash before tail case\n\n");
        //tail of main list
        if(curr -> next == NULL){


            printf("im in trash with tail case\n\n");
            head = curr;

            head -> previous = NULL;
            return head;
        }

        printf("im in trash before after tail case\n\n");

        //every other case

        //printf("this is the head value: %d\n\n", head -> value);
        head = curr;
        //printf("im in trash after head = curr\n\n");

        head -> previous = NULL;
        //printf("im in trash after head -> previous\n\n");

        head -> next = NULL;
        printf("im in trash after head -> next\n\n");

        printf("this is the head value: %d\n\n", head -> value);
        return head;

    }else{

        printf("im in trash inside else\n\n");
        trashCurr = head;
        while(trashCurr -> next != NULL){

            trashCurr = trashCurr -> next;
        }

        if(link2Delete == 0){

            temp = curr; 
            trashCurr -> next = temp;

            temp -> previous = trashCurr;
            trashCurr = temp;
            trashCurr -> next = NULL;
            return head;
        }

        //tail of main list
        if(curr -> next == NULL){

            temp = curr;
            trashCurr = temp;

            temp -> previous = trashCurr;           
            temp -> next = NULL;
            trashCurr -> next = temp;

            return head;
        }

        //every other case

        temp = curr;    
        temp -> previous = trashCurr;

        trashCurr -> next = temp;
        trashCurr = temp;
        trashCurr -> next = NULL;
        return head;

    }


}


void generateRandom(struct node *mainHead, int size){
    int i = 0;
    int link2Delete = 0;
    struct node *head = NULL;
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    int number2Delete = rand() % size + 1;


    printf("this is the rand number: %d\n", rand());    

    printf("this is the number of nodes to be deleted: %d\n", number2Delete);

    for (i = 0; i < number2Delete; i++) {
        // Pick a random node (payload) to delete.  
        link2Delete = (rand() % size);
        printf("this is the number of nodes in the list: %d\n", size);
        printf("this is the node to be deleted: %d\n", link2Delete);
        size--;

        if(link2Delete == 0){
            mainHead = modifyMainList(mainHead, link2Delete);
            //printf("this is the call return: %d\n\n",  addTrash(mainHead, link2Delete) -> value);
            head = addTrash (mainHead, link2Delete);

        }else{

            head = addTrash (mainHead, link2Delete);
            mainHead = modifyMainList(mainHead, link2Delete);
        }

    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried your program on debugger? That might highlight what could be the reason for Segmentation fault.

Comment: I do not have a debugger on this computer and unable to get one with this school computer

Comment: where is the main()?  I want to run it in my computer.

Comment: 'I do not have a debugger on this computer and unable to get one' - you must stop developing software as you don't have the necessary tools..  Tell your teaching staff this so that they can give their students what they need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code,

```
while(i != link2Delete){

    curr = curr -> next;
}
```

is an infinite loop if `link2Delete!=0`.

And also, not freeing in `head case`.

As the loop is infinite, `curr = curr->next` will keep on repeating and it will point to some garbage pointer (if loop condition is true). Then, it has undefined behaviour. And you might get SEGFAULT.

Comment: Okay, looks like that fixed that problem. now i am just getting segfaults elsewhere but seems to me they might just be logic errors, but i am not sure yet. Thank you